# Java: performance and complexity for code

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have two pieces of code like below:

```
code 1:

Optional.fromNullable(integerVsLongMap.get(id)).or(getDefaultLong());
```

and

```
code 2:

integerVsLongMap.contains(id) ? integerVsLongMap.get(id) : getDefaultLong();
```

I would like to know which piece of code is more efficient and preferable in terms of space and time complexity and in terms of coding practices, cause what I see is both do the same thing?

Comment: not a direct answer: have you thought of microbenchmarking this ? Besides that (in my opinion): code variant 2 doesn't look nice.

Comment: @Marged Not a direct answer? Maybe you meant "question"? Anyway, what's indirect here?

Comment: If using Java 7 or earlier, is there a restriction of non-null values in `integerVsLongMap`? If not, (2) is the only *correct* way to do it, since there may be a null value in the map. Correctness should trump efficiency and readability. If using Java 8, use `Map.getOrDefault`.

Comment: I wanted to say that my comment/answer is not directly that kind of reply that fully answers your question. That's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best, both in terms of performance and readability, would be to use

```
Long v = integerVsLongMap.getOrDefault(id, getDefaultLong())
```

in my opinion.

Performance is probably not a concern, but it can nevertheless be improved for both solutions:

- the first one creates an Optional instance every time
- the second one makes two map lookups when one is sufficient

The time complexity of all solutions is the one of the map lookup (O(1) for a HashMap, O(log(n)) for a TreeMap, for example).

Comment: He's not talking about performance but space and time complexity (I guess using Big-O notation), but yes that's also (or even more) important.

Answer (score 1):

Space and time complexity are always O(1), not depending on the size of the map. But if you look at real space and time needed

```
Long v = integerVsLongMap.getOrDefault(id, getDefaultLong())
```

and

```
integerVsLongMap.contains(id) ? integerVsLongMap.get(id) : getDefaultLong();
```

are the best solutions because don't creates new objects.

Internally the `getOrDefault` do exactly what the second code does.
Here the code of getOrDefault

```
public V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue) {
    Node<K,V> e;
    return (e = getNode(hash(key), key)) == null ? defaultValue : e.value;
}
```

Creating an `Optional` needs to create always a new Object.

If you need to use the returned value in a chain the best solution is with the `Optional`.